Eslint: why eslint-config-prettier needed only to skip formatting?
I was going through https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/upgrading-eslint-from-v8-to-v9-in-vue-js/ and I am wondering why the final example configuration in the tutorial looks like this:
import pluginVue from 'eslint-plugin-vue';
import vueTsEslintConfig from '@vue/eslint-config-typescript';
import skipFormatting from '@vue/eslint-config-prettier/skip-formatting';

export default [
  {
    name: 'app/files-to-lint',
    files: ['**/*.{js,mjs,ts,mts,vue}'],
  },
  {
    name: 'app/files-to-ignore',
    ignores: ['**/dist/**', '**/test-results/**', '**/coverage/**'],
  },
  ...pluginVue.configs['flat/recommended'],
  ...vueTsEslintConfig(),
  {
  skipFormatting,
];

what reason is there to add a @vue/eslint-config-prettier dependency only to skip formatting in the end, so you would run prettier as a standalone task after eslint? then why include the extra dependency in the first place?
